# NGINX - auth basic if $arg contains 'admin'

Tags: nginx, basic-authentication

Im trying to get my admin controller under auth_basic authentication. This is how my nginx config looks like :

```
location /index.php {
   if ($arg_r ~ admin) {
        auth_basic                          "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file                /etc/nginx/mywebsite/.htpasswd;
   }
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass php;
 }
```

I need to prompt a auth when the request contains 'admin' in the arg `r`, for example :

- /index.php?r=admin -> Auth
- /index.php?r=admin/anythinghere -> Auth
- /index.php?r=site/index -> No Auth

But not working, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation, auth_* are not allowed in "if"s. Maybe this could do the trick:

```
location = /index.php {
   if ($arg_r ~ admin) {
      rewrite ^ /_admin/index.php$is_args$args last;
   }
   include fastcgi_params;
   fastcgi_index index.php;
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
   fastcgi_pass php;
}

location /_admin/index.php {
   internal;
   auth_basic                          "Restricted";
   auth_basic_user_file                /etc/nginx/mywebsite/.htpasswd;
   include fastcgi_params;
   fastcgi_index index.php;
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
   fastcgi_pass php;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
   include fastcgi_params;
   fastcgi_index index.php;
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
   fastcgi_pass php;
}
```

Just duplicated location with auth enabled. "internal" directive restricts direct requests to this location.
And note I added "=" to the first location, it allows to avoid rewriting /index.phpadasdasdsdfadsf into /_auth/index.php

Comment: Mmmmm, if i correct my config as you has said, going to /index.php downloads me the index.php with the name of "Download", but at index.php?r=admin ask me to auth. What the f**k?

Comment: In place of his comments you need to include whatever mechanism you're using for processing php (e.g. fastcgi or proxy), without it ".php" files are just files.

Comment: i have the location ~ \.php at the end of the config

Comment: exact location = /index.php takes precedence over regex'ed one

Comment: then, should i put the \.php location content into  /index.php and /_admin/index.php ?

Comment: yes. Or just supply you full config file so i could help you

Comment: http://pastebin.com/s6WViZb1 , there you have! It's getting hard to do this, it seemed to be easier